# Ubuntu 11.10 and ATI/AMD Radeon 5650

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, ati, vgaswitcheroo

I have a laptop with freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10 and ATI 4200/AMD Radeon 5650 hybrid graphics. The problem is that I can't switch between integrated and discrete video while using Catalyst driver (ver 12.2). Catalyst tells me that I can switch on to discrete on next reboot but after that, the laptop still uses integrated video.

Additionally, my whole system is very slow when I'm using the Catalyst driver.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got it working here (Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit) for the first time since I bought this damn HP Pavilion 4045ea.

I removed every single iteration of fglrx, installed the ATI binary driver from the Software Centre, rebooted and ta-daa!

Unity looks better, full HD movies are finally playable and the whole system seems to be running better.

Comment: yes opensource driver works very much better than fglrx

Answer (score 1):

For the system slow when using Catalyst driver problem, install compizconfig-settings-manager. Then run it and select the OpenGL icon. Then DEselect the checkbox for Sync to Vblank.

Comment: i'm doing this immediately after installing driver and i can't see any difference. Besides i'm turned off all effects in compiz.
Very interesting that open source drivers works in several times  faster than fglrx, but my laptop has temperature near 73-75 degrees in maximum performance mode

Comment: Well, I am just letting you know that doing what my answer says helps resolve the fglrx performance problems for many users. It has nothing to do with using compiz effects, it is just a way to set an OpenGL setting. Try it or don't.